# With jquery ui draggable, is it possible to have different scrollsensitivity vertical versus horizontal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using [jquery ui draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-scrollSensitivity) and I realized that I want the scrollsensitivity to be much smaller when I am dragging up down (versus left / right).  Is this possible to have a different settings for vertical versus horizontal dragging?

Here is my current code

```
   $(".myDraggable").draggable(
            {
                stack: ".myDraggable",
                scroll: true,
                scrollSensitivity: 250,
                scrollSpeed: 40,
                revert: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0
                    };
                    return !event;
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Which version of jquery UI are you using?

Comment: @leora, we can't improve our answers if you don't provide feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated Answer

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/22bpbsrw/3/

I think detecting when a scroll event occurrs in the viewport actually works. You can set the scroll speed and sensitivity then.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0,
    lastScrollLeft = 0,
    delta = 5;
$('#viewPort').scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var sl = $(this).scrollLeft();

    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) > delta) {
        $("#draggable").draggable("option", "scrollSensitivity", 5);
        $("#draggable").draggable("option", "scrollSpeed", 10);
        (st > lastScrollTop) ? console.log('scroll down') : console.log('scroll up');
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }

    if (Math.abs(lastScrollLeft - sl) > delta) {
        $("#draggable").draggable("option", "scrollSensitivity", 100);
        $("#draggable").draggable("option", "scrollSpeed", 40);
        sl > lastScrollLeft ? console.log('scroll right') : console.log('scroll left');
        lastScrollLeft = sl;
    }
});
```

---

### Old Answer

*Left just in case it could help others.*

You cannot explicitly have different `scrollSensitivity` values for each direction. Maybe you could submit a ticket for that enhancement?

You might be able to change it via the drag function ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16293541/1085891)). See working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mbups?editors=001

```
drag: function(e) {    
  console.log($("#drag1").draggable( "option", "scrollSensitivity"));
  if(prevX == -1) { prevX = e.pageX; }
  // dragged left or right
  if(prevX > e.pageX || prevX < e.pageX) { // dragged right
      $("#drag1").draggable( "option", "scrollSensitivity", 100 );
  }
  prevX = e.pageX;
 
 if(prevY == -1) { prevY = e.pageY; } 
  // dragged up or down
  if(prevY > e.pageY || prevY < e.pageX) { // dragged down
      $("#drag1").draggable( "option", "scrollSensitivity", 1 );
  }
  prevY = e.pageY;
}
```

You could set the `scrollSensitivity` based on the direction of the dragged element.

Answer (score 1):

Allthough it seems the solution of JSuar works I want to give it a try, too.

### Solving the Problem with jQuery UI Draggable Widget is not possible.

There is **no explicit function** to get information about wether the object is moved vertical or horizontal. In fact in **most cases the object is moved in both directions**. But we could define our own function to look how the cursor was moved

### Use a custom function to get information about the dragged object

The idea is to fire an **event on mousemove** and check the cursorposition every time. After a **certain intervall** of mousemovements we **check the overall movement** to set the scrollsensitivity. In this case we just assume that the user will most likely drag in the same direction for the next movements.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vbov1pvc/)** is a working JSFiddle example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="viewPort">
    <div id="draggable">drag me</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#viewPort {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#draggable {
    color: #fff;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #333399;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:5px;
}
```

**JS**

```
//current count of how often we got the mouse positon
var count = 0;
//position of mouse at last function call
var lastPositionX;
var lastPositionY;
//how often we moved in one direction in the last intervall
var movedX;
var movedY;
//intervall to check movement again
var countIntervall = 30;

$("#draggable").draggable({
    scrollSensitivity: 1000,
    scrollSpeed: 40,
    revert: function (event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").originalPosition = {
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        };
        return !event;
    },
    drag: function (e) {
       setScrollSensivity();
    }
});

//init first mousepostion
$("#draggable").on('click', function() {
    lastPositionX = event.pageX;
    lastPositionY = event.pageY;
});

function setScrollSensivity(){
    count++;

    //get current mousepostion
    var currentPositionX = event.pageX; 
    var currentPositionY = event.pageY; 

    //increase if moved on chose axis
    if ( currentPositionX != lastPositionX ){
        movedX++;
    }

    if ( currentPositionY != lastPositionY ){
        movedY++;
    }

    //if moved more on x axis decrease sensivity, else increase.
    if (count == countIntervall){
        if (movedX > movedY){
            console.log("moving on X axis");
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable( "option", "scrollSensitivity", 10 );
        } else {
            console.log("moving on Y axis");
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable( "option", "scrollSensitivity", 200 );
        }
        //reset all the counters and start again
        count = 0;
        movedX = 0;
        movedY = 0;
    }
    //set last position for our next function call
    lastPositionX = currentPositionX;
    lastPositionY = currentPositionY;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks very similar to mine. What exactly is different other than expanding out the code?

Comment: My method does not rely on the scroll event so it could be used to set options just depending on which axis you move with your mouse.

Comment: That's a good point, but I included that in my answer listed as old answer.

Comment: Yeah it is similar. But triggering the event after every px moved results in changing the scroll sensivity 100 times a second. Since a user won't have the precision move the mouse only on the x or y axis. I saw that and thought it might could be improved. That's why i stated yours as already correct.